# combobox integer to observablelist

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm having problems setting an Integer value to an observable list.

I have the following code, and some Integer values in a combobox. When pressing the button I want to add the Integer from the combobox to the observable list. I'm able to do that with Strings, but this doesn't work with Integer. I also need to get the data in as integers as I need to do some calculation. Does anyone have an idea?

```
public class Resultat {
public SimpleStringProperty res_Auswärtsteam = new SimpleStringProperty();
public SimpleIntegerProperty res_Auswärtstore = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

public Integer getRes_auswärtstore() {
    return res_Auswärtstore.get();
}

public String getRes_auswärtsteam() {
    return res_Auswärtsteam.get();
}
```

}

```
public class Resultat_Controller implements Initializable {
// The table and columns
@FXML TableView<Resultat> result_tableview;
@FXML TableColumn result_Auswärtstore;
@FXML TableColumn result_Auswärtsteam;

@FXML Button result_btn_Hinzufügen;

@FXML ComboBox result_cbo_Auswärtstore;
@FXML ComboBox result_cbo_Auswärtsteam;

// The table's data
ObservableList<Resultat> data;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // Set up the table data

    result_Auswärtstore.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Resultat, Integer>("res_auswärtstore"));
    result_Auswärtsteam.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Resultat, Integer>("res_auswärtsteam"));

    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    result_tableview.setItems(data);

    result_cbo_Auswärtstore.getItems().clear();
    result_cbo_Auswärtstore.getItems().addAll("1", "2", "3", "4");
    result_cbo_Auswärtsteam.getItems().clear();
    result_cbo_Auswärtsteam.getItems().addAll("String 1", "String 2", "String 3", "String 4");
}    

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Resultat resultateintrag = new Resultat();
    resultateintrag.res_Auswärtsteam.setValue(result_cbo_Auswärtsteam.getValue().toString());
    resultateintrag.res_Auswärtstore.setValue(2);
    data.add(resultateintrag);
}
```

}

At the moment I set a default value of 2 (which should obviously go away).
Thanks

Comment: Your `@FXML` fields lack generic types.  Change `ComboBox` to `ComboBox<Integer>` and `ComboBox<String>`.  Similarly, the TableColumn fields should be `TableColumn<Resultat, Integer>` and `TableColumn<Resultat, String>` respectively.  The documentation for [ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) and [TableColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html) has more information.

Comment: Also the cell factory for `result_Auswärtsteam` should be a `PropertyValueFactory<Resultat, String>` since the property type it references is a `String`

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Adjusting the types solved my issue thanks a lot.

Comment: @VGR please provide your comment as an answer, so user3721905 can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your `@FXML` fields lack generic types. Change `ComboBox` to `ComboBox<Integer>` and `ComboBox<String>`. Similarly, the TableColumn fields should be `TableColumn<Resultat, Integer>` and `TableColumn<Resultat, String>` respectively. The documentation for [ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) and [TableColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html) has more information.